# change tabs in google custom search with Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-custom-search

Once you land on the results page for a Google Custom Search, how can I use javascript or JQuery to change the tabs? Changing the tab class does not seem to work. Here is the link to my test search I'm using to develop this:

http://www.wwfblogs.org/test/TESTRESULTS.html?cx=003443374396369277624%3Abczohksdgqy&ie=UTF-8&x=elephant&sa=

Comment: Without looking at your code, have you tried triggering a click event on the tab you want?

Comment: looks like .trigger("click"); works!

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to select initial tab that is not the "ALL" tab, you can use defaultToRefinement param in your element:

```
<gcse:search defaultToRefinement="games"></gcse:search>
```

Selecting tabs with jquery does not work because the tabs are rendered after your jquery script finished. I'm not sure there is an event/callback you could use to know when the tabs and results finish rendering.